# SQL: A Count that merges/joins two columns

Tags: sql, join, count

A company wants to know what has happened since the beginning of 1999 on hiring. The human resources manager has asked you to
produce a count of the employees hired since then, broken down by both age and gender simultaneously (i.e. 17 males, 25 females, etc.). Write a query that does that.

This is what I have so far. I couldn't figure out how to merge two columns simultaneously. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(*) AS "Number of employees"
FROM Employee
WHERE Age and Gender
GROUP BY EmployeeID
HAVING COUNT(*) BEGIN = 1999
```

Comment: Could you please provide your table columns, and sample data in your question? And If I understand your question correctly, [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) will be good for you to start!

Comment: Here's some thoughts. Do you have a query that gets results "broken down" by just gender? `GROUP BY EmployeeId` is going to get a count "broken down" by employee id.  Think about replacing the references to `EmployeeId` with a different expression, like gender. As far as breaking down by "age", is that the current age of the employee, or their age they were hired? To get that, it seems like you'd need to know the difference (in full years) between the "date of hire" and the employee "date of birth".

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty much sure about your requirement but the right way to write a query is as following and this may fulfill your requirement with slight changes...

```
SELECT Gender, COUNT(*) AS "Number of employees", Age
FROM Employee
WHERE year(column_name) >= 1999 --Give a real date column here
GROUP BY Age, Gender
```

Please provide table structure and complete desired output for the exact answer.